# Change video src without stopping HTML5 video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

How to change HTML5 video quality? This is my script up to now. It works but video starts from the beginning. Is there a way to change video quality like YouTube without stopping the video.?

```
<video src="videos/nesemdonti_1080p.mp4" id="video" autoplay></video>
<div id="720p" class="quality">720p</div>
```

```
$("#720p").click(function() {
    $('video').attr("src", "videos/nesemdonti_720p.mp4");
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nz3eLrt2/3

Comment: Have you seen this: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_quality  ?

Comment: I'm not using YouTube API. I'll use pure HTML5 @koopajah

Comment: (rexhin, your clip is sexy, LOL)

Comment: hahah @JonDinham She is from Albania. Me too. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mMs_XJT6YFc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is that we have to make sure the 720p video is ready to be played.

HTML5:

```
<video id="preload" style="display:none;">
</video>

<video src="videos/nesemdonti_1080p.mp4" id="video" autoplay>
</video>
<div id="720p" class="quality">720p</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#720p").click(function() {
    $("preload").attr("src", "videos/nesemdonti_720p.mp4");

    $("preload").on("canplay",function(){
        $('video').attr("src", "videos/nesemdonti_720p.mp4");
    });
});
```

The 'canplay' event occurs when the browser can start playing the specified audio/video.
See: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_canplay.asp

Comment: What about currentTime? Should I save it and than start the second video from there? @Jon Dinham

Comment: huh, currentTime? that's your own operational specification for the website